# Is the Marvel anti hero/villain Taskmaster a really good actor?

Tags: marvel, the-taskmaster

Is the Marvel anti hero/villain Taskmaster a really good actor?

He can portray that he is simply "a man" and not who he actually is and the way he does it "though as elaborate as DC's Batman but without the malice of the bat". And similar but unlike Batman, Marvel's Taskmaster can make friends quite easily with his enemy's because of his facade and many comics I've read makes me think he is an excellent actor.

It would be ironic for someone playing as Taskmaster to be Taskmaster acting as someone else.

Is there any comics which show Taskmaster as an actor? And not just a mercenary?

His personality just made me think how good of an actor is Marvel's Taskmaster.

Answer can be from comics, movie, anywhere.

Is there any comics which show Taskmaster as an actor? Like on stage or acting as someone else and is he any good?

Answer (score 0):

No memory of Taskmaster ever appearing on a stage, but I do offer this moment from "Avengers" #26, Volume 3, (2000-ish).  Posing as Captain America, Taskmaster fools an assortment of heroes and cons them into being "emergency" Avengers for a special assignment.  In the end, the mission requirements and "Cap's" demands are what expose him, not his acting ability.

What probably stops Taskmaster from impersonating heroes all the time is his, well, cowardice.  Since his first appearance, he is on record as hating to take a beating, hating to be on the front line taking risks, and always abandons his students/schools when the heroes are closing in tight.

[image]

Answer (score -5):

As [@Raj has said](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216555/is-the-marvel-anti-hero-villain-taskmaster-a-really-good-actor/217213#comment591928_216555):

> Not on stage, but there is a comic where he dresses as Deadpool and manages to fool even the head of H.A.M.M.E.R. (Norman Osborne) and the Thunderbolts.

Comment: Solely copying a comment as your whole answer doesn't really make it a good answer. Instead find the comic where this happened and [edit] it in to prove whether or not he is a good actor.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't find the comic anywhere at all on the internet I looked for hours and there was only one image on the entire internet of the comic